# Maven - how to set version of parent in submodule

Tags: maven

I want to set version for all modules in main module.

Main module:

```
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject-main-module</artifactId>
<version>${myproject.version}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
   <myproject.version>3.1.0-SNAPSHOT</myproject.version>
   <myproject.parent.version>1.1</myproject.parent.version>
</properties>
```

Submodule:

```
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject-submodule</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
   <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
   <artifactId>myproject-main-module</artifactId>
   <version>${myproject.version}</version>
</parent>
```

Why ${myproject.version} is not seen by submodule and what I should do if I want to set version only once for all modules.

Comment: You can't do this, you will have to specify the parent version explicitly in each module.

Comment: Starting with Maven 3.5.0-beta-1 this is possible (not yet offically released). Apart from that why is it a problem you will do that only manually at the intial setup time afterwards you will change the versions by using maven-release-plugin or versions-maven-plugin...